# Trouble running Docco on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, docco

I'm having trouble running Docco on Windows 7. I did the following:

1. downloaded and installed python and perl
2. installed node js
3. Run npm install -g coffee-script
4. Run easy_install pygments
5. Run npm install -g pygments
6. Run npm install -g docco

I navigated to the directory with javascript source:

```
C:\javascript>docco animation.js
docco: animation.js -> docs\animation.html

fs.js:427
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\javascript\docs\animation.html'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
    at write (C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docco\docco.js:111:15)
    at C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docco\docco.js:29:11

    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: `C:\javascript\docs\ ` doesn't exist?

Comment: I think it's supposed to generate the folder docs and the file animation.html after parsing animation.js . I'm not sure why it's expecting for it to exist beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Docco sources, this is the problem:

```
ensureDirectory = function(dir, callback) {
  return exec("mkdir -p " + dir, function() {
    return callback();
  });
};
```

In other words: it assumes that an executable called `mkdir` exists, and uses it to creates the necessary directories (including the output directory). But `mkdir` is a Unix-ism, and (usually) not available on Windows. So it fails (and since Docco isn't checking for any errors, it happily continues as if nothing happened...).

**EDIT:** seems these issues [were fixed recently](https://github.com/jashkenas/docco/pull/181), so if you use the Github-hosted version of Docco you might get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your response robert. I did the installation on Friday of last week so I think I have the latest. However, do you know of a mkdir executable that I can download for Windows?

Comment: If you installed docco using npm, you don't necessarily have to be using the latest version: the [Github version](https://github.com/jashkenas/docco) might not yet be released to the NPM registry yet. As for `mkdir`, I think you could try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (but since I don't use Windows myself, I'm not entirely sure).